# How to pass radio button value as route parameter in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, laravel-6

I want to pass the selected radio button value as a parameter with Laravel route.

My Route is:

```
Route::resource('/datas','DataController');
```

From this route, I am aiming to call localhost:8000/datas/{data}

My data.blade.php is:

```
<form id="dataform" action="{{ route('datas.show')}}" method="GET">
   <table class="table">
      <tr>
         <th>Select bullet</th>
         <th>SL NO</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
      @foreach ($datas $key => $data)
         <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" id="data{{$data->id}}" name="data" value={{$data->id}}></option></td>
            <td>{{$key}}</td>
            <td>{{$data->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$data->age}}</td>
         </tr>
      @endforeach
   </table>
   <button type="submit" id="edit_submit" class="btn btn-default">Show</button>                    </form>
```

My show function will be...

```
public function show($id)
   {
      //Code to showing data and redirect to show page
   }
```

I want to get value of this radio button(given below).

```
<td><input type="radio" id="data{{$data->id}}" name="data" value={{$data->id}}>
```

and include it as a parameter with the Form action below

```
<form id="dataform" action="{{ route('datas.show')}}" method="GET">
```

Comment: You need to use javascript to get the value from the radio input and update the form's action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes to this code.
Changed button to anchor tag.
So my blade.php is:-

```
   <table class="table">
      <tr>
         <th>Select bullet</th>
         <th>SL NO</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
      @foreach ($datas $key => $data)
         <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" id="data{{$data->id}}" name="data" value={{$data->id}}></option></td>
            <td>{{$key}}</td>
            <td>{{$data->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$data->age}}</td>
         </tr>
      @endforeach
   </table>
   <a  href="javascript:showfunction()" id="showlink" class="btn btn-default">Show</a>
```

and I added a javascript function too.

```
<script>
    function showfunction(){
       var id = document.querySelector('input[name = "data"]:checked').value;
       var url = '{{route("admin.questions.show",":id")}}';
       url=url.replace(':id',id);
       document.location.href=url;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't accomplish that with just HTML/Blade. You need javascript (or a javascript framework) for the live changes to work since the parameter in your form's action route depends on the value of the selected radio.

```
action="{{ route('datas.show', [ 'id' => [insert id here] ])}}"
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can click the check mark button if this answer solved the issue.